# Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps

Tags: c#, .net, latex, ghostscript, pdflatex

I have a .net windows form application that uses ghostscript. Only on 1 machine do i get an error message. On all others (100s) it works find. This is in a Citrix environment.

The error is "AFPL Ghostscript 8.53: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps"

I have checked and the file does exist.

Comment: Are the environment path variables the same on that machine?  Are there any different user permissions on that machine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the path variables are the same and the permissions on the machine are the same.

Answer (score 26):

I've had a similar problem when compiling a latex file on OSx (`pdflatex *.tex`).
The problem arose because of `gs` installed by MacTeX.
The command `pdflatex` was using the command gs installed by MacTex and not the one installed by `brew`.
I fixed the problem by running the following command `brew link --overwrite ghostscript`

Comment: Same for GS installed via X11.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem when calling the GS dll from a Delphi application; I solved it by setting the environment variable.

From the documentation: Ghostscript tries directories in this order:

1. The current directory (unless disabled by the `-P-` switch);
2. The directories specified by `-I` switches in the command line, if any;
3. The directories specified by the `GS_LIB` environment variable, if any.

Comment: The Ghostscript installer also adds registry keys for the `GS_LIB` directory and also searches there.